# How to differentiate a function constructed through FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, maximum

I am trying to maximize a function which has as a variable another function that was solved numerically using FindRoot.  My code is below.I start by defining some parameters

```
`alpha = .2;
beta = .1;
n2 = n - n1 ;
sigma = 5;
d = 1.25;
eta = .1
n = 100;
F = 1;
theta = .6;
delta = .8;
Phi = -((alpha + beta)/(sigma - 1) + eta (1 - delta) - theta);
A2 = 1;
T1 = b1^(sigma - 1) (1 + t1)^(-sigma);
T2 = b2^(sigma - 1) (1 + t2)^(-sigma);
phi1 = (b2/d)^(sigma - 1);
phi2 = (b1/d)^(sigma - 1);
```

I then define two functions.

Function 1:

```
v1lim[tau1_, t1_, tau2_, t2_, b1_, b2_, A1_, n1_] = 
  A1 (tau1 + alpha t1 (1 - tau1)/(1 + t1) + 
      t1 beta T1 ((1 - tau1) T2 (1 + 
             t2) - (T2 - phi2)/(T1 - phi1) phi1 (1 - tau2) n2/
            n1)/(T1 (1 + t1) T2 (1 + t2) - phi1 phi2))^
    eta ((1 - tau1)^(sigma - (1 - alpha - beta))/(1 + 
         t1)^(alpha sigma))^(1/(sigma - 1)) ((T1 T2 - phi1 phi2)/(T2 -
         phi2))^(beta/(sigma - 1)) n1^(-Phi);
```

Function 2:

```
v2lim[tau1_, t1_, tau2_, t2_, b1_, b2_, A1_, n1_] = 
  A2 (tau2 + alpha t2 (1 - tau2)/(1 + t2) + 
      t2 beta T2 ((1 - tau2) T1 (1 + 
             t1) - (T1 - phi1)/(T2 - phi2) phi1 (1 - tau1) n1/
            n2)/(T1 (1 + t1) T2 (1 + t2) - phi1 phi2))^
    eta ((1 - tau2)^(sigma - (1 - alpha - beta))/(1 + 
         t2)^(alpha sigma))^(1/(sigma - 1)) ((T1 T2 - phi1 phi2)/(T1 -
         phi1))^(beta/(sigma - 1)) n2^(-Phi);
```

I equate these functions to solve for the variable  "nilim"below

```
nilim[tau1_?NumericQ, t1_?NumericQ, tau2_?NumericQ, t2_?NumericQ, 
      b1_?NumericQ, b2_?NumericQ, A1_?NumericQ] := 
     n1 /. FindRoot[
       v1lim[tau1, t1, tau2, t2, b1, b2, A1, n1] - 
         v2lim[tau1, t1, tau2, t2, b1, b2, A1, n1] == 0, {n1, 50}]
```

I then want to insert that value back into function 1 and maximize the function numerically for "t1,tau1,t2,tau2".

I have used the following method

```
 FindRoot[Grad[
   v1lim[tau1, t1, tau2, t2, 1, 1, 1, 
    nilim[tau1?Numericq, t1?Numericq, tau2?Numericq, t2?Numericq, 1, 1, 1]], {tau1, t1, tau2, t2}] == {0, 
   0, 0, 0}, {{tau1, .1}, {t1, -.1}, {tau2, .1}, {t2, -.1}}]
```

But I get the following errors

```
FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {0.138682 ((-0.167772+Power[<<2>>] Power[<<1>>])/(-0.4096+Power[<<2>>]))^0.025 ((1. +<<1>>)^4.3/(1. +t1)^1.)^(1/4) ((0.2 t1 (1. +Times[<<2>>]))/Plus[<<2>>]+tau1+(0.1 t1 (Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<4>>]))/(Plus[<<2>>]^5 Plus[<<2>>]))^0.1-0.138682 (<<1>>/<<1>>)^0.025 (<<1>>/<<1>>)^(1/4) (<<1>>/(<<1>>^5 <<1>>)+<<1>>/<<1>>+tau2)^0.1} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {n1} = {50.}.



 General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::nlnum will be suppressed during this calculation.

    FindRoot::vloc: The variable #2 cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values.

    FindRoot::vloc: The variable #2 cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values.

    FindRoot::vloc: The variable #2 cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values.

    General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::vloc will be suppressed during this calculation.

    FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

    FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

    FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
```

There is probably a simpler way of doing this.  I would appreciate any suggestions.

All that I am getting as a result is my initial code again.

```
   FindRoot[Grad[
  v1lim[tau1, t1, tau2, t2, 1, 1, 1, 
    nilim[tau1, t1, tau2, t2, 1, 1, 1]],{tau1, t1, tau2, t2}] == {0, 
   0, 0, 0}, {{tau1, 0.1}, {t1, -0.1}, {tau2, 0.1}, {t2, -0.1}}]
```

Comment: It would make it easier to read if you explicitly identified the two functions mentioned in the first sentence. -- Second, why are there two definitions of `nilim`?  Try commenting out the first one.

Comment: (1) Do the parameters `alpha` etc. have numerical values? If not, `FindRoot` cannot be used. You'd need a symbolic solver. (2) Omit the four instances of `?Numericq` in the final `FindRoot`. The pattern test `?` is for ***defining*** functions (and replacement rules).

Comment: Yes, all parameters in the equations are given numerical values in the beginning of the notebook so the only variables are "tau1, tau2, t1, t2" which are the variables I am trying to simulate.

Comment: Well it "works" for me if I remove `?Numericq`, but it works poorly because I have given it bad (I assume) parameter values. Can you post your actual values?

Comment: I have taken   `?Numericq ` out of my initial code but I do not get a result.  All I get back is my initial code `FindRoot[Grad[
  v1lim[tau1, t1, tau2, t2, 1, 1, 1, 
    nilim[tau1, t1, tau2, t2, 1, 1, 1]],{tau1, t1, tau2, t2}] == {0, 
   0, 0, 0}, {{tau1, 0.1}, {t1, -0.1}, {tau2, 0.1}, {t2, -0.1}}]`

Comment: I get a solution. But I don't see how I can be of further help without the values for the parameters.

Comment: I have added the parameters to the original question.